# Postgres directed graph traversal up AND down

Tags: algorithm, postgresql, graph, postgresql-9.5, recursive-cte

I've got a problem which I can solve for small data sets but fails on large ones with (possibly) unclean data.

The database is an implementation of an acyclic (hopefully) graph in PostgreSQL. With three tables

```
vertex_elements: id
edges: id, parent_id, child_id
element_associations: id, user_id, object_id (both are vertex elements, but it unconnected graphs)
```

I have a set of *user_ids* from which I derive *element_associations* and a starting *vertex_element* in the graph, and I want to find all child nodes are accessible from an *element_association* with one of the *user_ids*. A node is considered to be accessible if it, or one of its *ancestors* is one of the candidate *object_ids* of an *element_association*.

The graph is relatively triangular in shape (few root nodes with many leaf nodes), and from a starting *vertex element*, my strategy is the following:

1. Check the current *vertext_element* against the list of candidate *element_associations*; if it's good, all descendants are accessible, otherwise go to...
2. Check if the ancestors of the current *vertex_element* are in the list of candidate *element_associations*. Similarly to (1), if it's a hit, then all ancestors are accessible, otherwise go to...
3. Traverse to each child *vertex_element* (breadth first search) and follow steps 1 & 2.

The issue arises when I want to avoid double-checking the same ancestor *vertex_elements*. The main query is a traversal downwards, checking each descendant's accessibility with a set of candidate *element_associations*

```
        WITH RECURSIVE edges_recursive(child_id, parent_id, matching_element_association_id) AS (
          (
            SELECT e1.child_id, e1.parent_id, ea.id
            FROM edges e1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN element_associations ea ON e1.child_id = ea.object_id
              AND ea.id IN (?)
            WHERE parent_id = ?
          )
          UNION
          (
            SELECT e2.child_id, e2.parent_id, ea.id
            FROM edges e2
            INNER JOIN assignments_recursive
            ON edges_recursive.child_id = e2.parent_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN element_associations ea 
            ON edges_recursive.child_id = ea.object_id
              AND ea.id IN (?)
            WHERE edges_recursive.matching_element_association_id IS NULL
          )
        )

        SELECT edges_recursive.child_id
        FROM edges_recursive
        WHERE edges_recursive.matching_element_association_id IS NOT NULL
```

However, there is an addition recursive subquery which checks each *vertex_element's* within the LEFT OUTER JOIN element_associations which looks like

```
ea.id IN (
  WITH RECURSIVE parent_edges_recursive(child_id, parent_id, matching_element_association_id) AS (
    (
      SELECT edges.child_id, edges.parent_id, ea.id
      FROM edges
      LEFT OUTER JOIN element_associations ea 
      ON ea.id IN (?) AND edges.parent_id = ea.object_id
      WHERE edges.child_id = e1.parent_id AND edges.parent_id != e1.parent_id
    )
    UNION
    (
      SELECT edges.child_id, edges.parent_id. ea.id
      FROM edges
      JOIN parent_edges_recursive 
      ON parent_edges_recursive.parent_id = edges.child_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN element_associations ea
      ON ea.id IN (?) AND edges.parent_id = ea.object_id
      WHERE parent_edges_recursive.matching_element_association_id IS NULL
    )
    SELECT parent_edges_recursive.matching_element_association_id
    FROM parent_edges_recursive
    WHERE parent_edges_recursive.matching_element_association_id IS NOT NULL
    LIMIT 1
 )
)
```

The issue with this is that there is that the subqueries tend to avoid traversing the same parent vertex twice; however, there is no guarantee that as we traverse down the graph through the descendants that we won't retread previously evaluated ancestors. For small data sets, this is fine and the performance is *okay*; however, it's ridiculously unscalable, and is extremely unresilient to cycles.

What I need to do is preserve the information about what parent *vertex_elements* I have already traversed between subqueries so that I avoid retreading steps; however, I am stuck on how to do this in a singular query.

Answer (score 2):

> What I need to do is preserve the information about what parent
>   vertex_elements I have already traversed between subqueries so that I
>   avoid retreading steps;

Without studying your queries in detail: you can do that by collecting IDs in an **array**. Code examples:

- [Query to find circular references](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64663/query-to-find-circular-references/64736#64736)
- [Visiting a directed graph as if it were an undirected one, using a recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764701/visiting-a-directed-graph-as-if-it-were-an-undirected-one-using-a-recursive-que/8765594#8765594)

Comment: You are absolutely correct that within a single ancestor subquery I can collect the IDs in an array; however I don't think I can pass the IDs collected in the parent traversal between subqueries, so I could possibly retread steps between. You've neatly identified the crux of the issue -- I want to share that data between each execution of the subquery to avoid repetitions.